# Initialize object type to corresponding empty value in python

Tags: python

I have a class that contains a dictionary of properties `current_properties`, the properties that can be added and their corresponding data types are predefined in `valid_properties` dictionary:

```
self.valid_properties = {'name': str, 'number': int, 'point_data': list}
self.current_properties = {'name': 'user_1'}
```

Now, I want to write a method that initializes every new added property to its corresponding empty value. e.g. `number` is `int`, once added, new state should be:

```
self.current_properties = {'name': 'user_1', 'number': 0}
```

if I add `point_data` the new state should be:

```
self.current_properties = {'name': 'user_1', 'number': 0, 'point_data':[]}
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: "every new added property" - how do you "add" new properties?

Answer (score 4):

You can look up the type from `valid_properties` using whatever key you want to insert, then use `()` to instantiate an object of that type.

```
>>> valid_properties = {'name': str, 'number': int, 'point_data': list}
>>> current_properties = {'name': 'user_1'}
>>> current_properties
{'name': 'user_1'}
>>> current_properties['number'] = valid_properties['number']()
>>> current_properties
{'number': 0, 'name': 'user_1'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
valid_properties = {'name': str, 'number': int, 'point_data': list}
current_properties = {'name': 'user_1'}

current_properties['number'] = valid_properties['number']()
current_properties['point_data'] = valid_properties['point_data']()

print(current_properties)
# {'name': 'user_1', 'number': 0, 'point_data': []}
```

**How?**

```
>>> k = int()                                               
>>> k                                                       
0                                                           
>>> k = list()                                              
>>> k                                                       
[]
```

**`int()`**:

Takes number or string to be converted to integer object, and base of the number as parameters. If no parameters are passed, returns `0`.

**`list()`**:

Takes an iterator as parameter. If no parameters are passed, it creates an empty list.